# Python Multi-Processing List Issue

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

I am attempting to dynamically open and parse through several text files (~10) to extract a particular value from key, for which I am utilizing multi-processing within Python to do this. My issue is that the function that I am calling writes particular data to a class list which I can see in the method, however outside the method that list is empty. Refer to the following:

class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    __id_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.process_wrapper()
```

Caller Method:

```
def process_wrapper(self):
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import multiprocessing

    info_file = 'info*'
    file_list = []

    p = Pool(processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)

    for file_name in Path('c:/').glob('**/*/' + info_file):
        file_list.append(str(os.path.join('c:/', file_name)))

    p.map_async(self.get_ids, file_list)

    p.close()
    p.join()

    print(self.__id_list) # this is showing as empty
```

Worker method:

```
def get_ids(self, file_name):        
    try:
        with open(file_name) as data:
            for line in data:
                temp_split = line.split()
                for item in temp_split:
                    value_split = str(item).split('=')
                    if 'id' == value_split[0].lower():
                        if int(value_split[1]) not in self._id_list:
                            self.__id_list.append(int(value_split[1]))
    except:
        raise FileReadError(f'There was an issue parsing "{file_name}".')
    print(self.__id_list) # here the list prints fine
```

Comment: Either of the answers useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

The map call returns a AysncResult class object.  you should use that to wait for the processing to finish before checking self.__id_list.   also you might consider returning a local list, collected those lists and aggregating them into the final list.

Comment: So in terms of waiting for the list to finish, isn't that what the 'p.join' does? Also if the function writes to the class list in memory, how cannot that be referenced outside the function? Do you have an example of a local list?

Comment: if you used map that would be the case.  I am thinking that you get a different behavior (sorry have not used map_asynch recently) with the asynch version,  its going to be returning (I think) after it spawns  off the workers,  not when they return.

Comment: I have used map and map runs the way you describe,  when the join is returned from the map is done and the methods have exited.

Comment: fyi,  map and map_async both use a _map_async mehtod within Pool.  difference is that map calls get method on the returned object from the internal method and returns that value.the asynch version returns the object returned and lets you call get.

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you have a typo in your `get_ids` method (`self._id_list` instead of `self.__id_list`). You can see it if you wait for the result:

```
result = p.map_async(self.get_ids, file_list)
result.get()
```

2. When a new child process is created, it gets a **copy** of the parent's address space however any subsequent changes (either by parent or child) are not reflected in the memory of the other process. They each have their own private address space.

Example:

```
$ cat fork.py 
import os

l = []
l.append('global')

# Return 0 in the child and the child’s process id in the parent
pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:
    l.append('child')
    print(f'Child PID: {os.getpid()}, {l}')
else:
    l.append('parent')
    print(f'Parent PID: {os.getpid()}, {l}')

print(l)

$ python3 fork.py 
Parent PID: 9933, ['global', 'parent']
['global', 'parent']
Child PID: 9934, ['global', 'child']
['global', 'child']
```

Now back to your problem, you can use [multiprocessing.Manager.list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager) to create an object that is shared between processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool

m = Manager()
self.__id_list = m.list()
```

**Docs:** [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

or use threads as your workload seems to be I/O bound anyway:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

p = ThreadPool(processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)
```

Alternatively check [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)